# unixodbc can't write the trace file

Tags: linux, postgresql, unixodbc

My unixodbc can connect to PostgreSQL,but the unixodbc always write the wrong trace file.
I set the trace file in /tmp/odbc.log but unixodbc always write it in /tmp/sql.log.
Where are wrong in my setting?

---odbcinst -j---

> unixODBC 2.3.2
>
> DRIVERS............: /usr/local/unixodbc/etc/odbcinst.ini
>
> SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /usr/local/unixodbc/etc/odbc.ini
>
> FILE DATA SOURCES..: /usr/local/unixodbc/etc/ODBCDataSources
>
> USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
>
> SQLULEN Size.......: 4
>
> SQLLEN Size........: 4
>
> SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 2

---odbc.ini---

> [root@mynewdb_test bin]# cat /usr/local/unixodbc/etc/odbc.ini
>
> [PostgreSQL]
>
> Driver = pg
>
> Description = Test2PG
>
> Servername = 10.2.22.155
>
> PORT = 5444
>
> Database = testdb
>
> password = u1

---odbcinst.ini---

> [root@mynewdb_test bin]# cat /usr/local/unixodbc/etc/odbcinst.ini
>
> [pg]
>
> driver=/usr/local/93AS/connectors/odbc/lib/edb-odbc.so
>
> Trace = yes
> TraceFile = /tmp/odbc.log

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

can you just try like below:

cat /usr/local/unixodbc/etc/odbcinst.ini

[pg]

driver=/usr/local/93AS/connectors/odbc/lib/edb-odbc.so

[ODBC]

TraceFile=/tmp/odbc.log

Trace=1

Also,please delete the previous entries in both file

Comment: still no tracing for me

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and see this question. This works for me. Hope it can help others.

Add this to odbcinst.ini

```
[ODBC]
Trace        = Yes
TraceFile    = /tmp/sql.log
ForceTrace   = Yes
```

Source:　[FreeTDS Logging](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/logging.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and here my solutions

nano /etc/odbcinst.ini and add this

```
[ODBC]
Trace      = Yes
TraceFile  = /tmp/odbc.log
ForceTrace = Yes
```

but that didn't work for me,and i changed Trace File Directory like this;

```
 TraceFile =/home/your_user/tmp/odbc.txt
```

after this changed odbc trace start worked.

Answer (score 0):

User file i.e /home/user/.odbcinst.ini gets overwritten somehow please try to add it in /etc/odbcinst.ini which should take effect.